# C++ specific solution to the error: variable 't' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++

The following C++ program compiles well but gives the following error when running(`Runtime check failure`):

> The variable 't' is being used without being initialized

```
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


void foo (int * count)

{
    *count=90; 

}

int main()


{

    int *t; 

    foo(t); 

    cout<<t[0]<<endl;

    return 0; 

}
```

I would remove this error in C like this:

```
int main()


{

    int *t; 

    t= (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); 

    foo(t); 

    cout<<t[0]<<endl;


    getch(); 
    return 0; 

}
```

What is the C++ specific solution to this error?

Comment: You want to do some research on what `new` does.

Comment: read your code again, did you find one version have one more line? and read error message again, do you understand it?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you have a particular reason not to, best to allocate on the stack rather than on the heap:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo (int *count)
  *count = 90; 
}

int main() {
  int t; 
  foo(&t); 
  std::cout << t << "\n";
}
```

If you really must allocate on the heap, prefer smart-pointers (like `std::unique_ptr`) to owning raw-pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void foo (int *count) {
  *count = 90; 
}

int main() {
  auto t = std::make_unique<int>();             // C++14
  // auto t = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int());  // C++11
  foo(t.get()); 
  std::cout << *t << "\n";
}
```

then you don't need to call `delete` (or `new` in C++14).

Comment: +1, nothing to do with `new`. The only requirement is that the pointer point to a valid `int` object. It doesn't matter how it has been allocated.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer should be initialized to point to a specific memory address before it is used. If this was not the case, it could be pointing to anything. This can lead to extremely unpleasant consequences to the program. For instance, the operating system will probably prevent you from accessing memory that it knows your program doesn't own: this will cause your program to crash. If it let you use the memory, you could mess with the memory of any running program--for instance, if you had a document opened in Word, you could change the text! Fortunately, Windows and other modern operating systems will stop you from accessing that memory and cause your program to crash. To avoid crashing your program, you should always initialize pointers before you use them.

It is also possible to initialize pointers using free memory. This allows dynamic allocation of memory. It is useful for setting up structures such as linked lists or data trees where you don't know exactly how much memory will be needed at compile time, so you have to get memory during the program's execution.

Comment: How would you initialize the memory without malloc() (and similar stuffs that will allocate in free area) ?

Comment: Either you can use `new` as mentioned by someone already or use `calloc()`.
In your query, the pointer has been made as `t` and then you have to allocate it in your memory. You can allocate it in either heap or stack. `calloc()` will help you allocate the memory before the initialization.

Comment: Anyway, I have run your program [see here](http://ideone.com/I7gM3v) and it ran successfully. So, basically it depends on the compiler also how it manages the memory allocations.